# Can someone explain me how I use Command(Action, CanExecute)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want `CanExecute` to turn to `true` when my 5 entries are validated.

Right now I've got this which is binded to my send-button

```
SendCommand = new Command(() => SendData());
```

I got no idea how to use CanExecute and how to set this value to true when all 5 entries are validated.

Has somebody a reference or an advice?

Comment: You need to show us the source or documentation of `Command` there is no `Command` class built in to .NET that implements `ICommand`

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Command/ do you mean something like that?

Comment: And when you look at the documentation for the constructor https://developer.xamarin.com/api/constructor/Xamarin.Forms.Command.Command/p/System.Action%7BSystem.Object%7D/System.Func%7BSystem.Object,System.Boolean%7D/ what in that documentation don't you undserstand about how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it thanks to @Scott Chamberlain. Sorry for the dumb question .... it was as easy as you would expect.

```
SendCommand = new Command(() => SendData(),() => CanSend());
```

Edit: Make sure you add the `EventHandler` and raise him in the setters of your booleans.

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
```

I did it like that:

```
public bool CanExecute()
    {
        if (IsValid1 && IsValid2 && IsValid3 && IsValid4 && IsValid5)
        {
            return true;
        } else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and like

```
public bool IsValid1 
    {
        get => _isvalid1;
        set
        {
            _isvalid1 = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsValid1)));
            ((Command)SendCommand).ChangeCanExecute();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to refresh with ChangeCanExecute when condition CanSend changes.

Comment: @evk yep you were right. called `((Command)SendCommand).ChangeCanExecute();` and it is working just fine!